# Нужна ли запятая перед "не подумав"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастия

Сказал не подумав.

Ляпнул не подумав (подумавши).

Сказал я просто не подумав.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Не обособляются одиночные деепричастия**, которые окончательно утратили глагольное значение, перешли в разряд наречий или приобрели наречное значение.

Такие деепричастия обычно являются обстоятельствами образа действия (отвечают на вопросы *как? каким образом?*), **сливаются** со сказуемым в одно целое, **не отделяются** от сказуемого паузой и чаще всего стоят сразу **после сказуемого** [как в первых двух вариантах]:

*шёл не останавливаясь, вошла не постучавшись, болтала не переставая, жили не прячась.*

1. **В большинстве случаев** в выражениях "сказал не подумав" и "ляпнул не подумав / не подумавши" запятая не ставится.

*Ладно, на самом деле я **сказал не подумав**, правда.

Вот так всегда, **ляпну не подумавши**, а потом жалею.

Последнее слово было произнесено с изрядной долей сарказма и даже презрения, так что я уже пожалел, что **ляпнул не подумав**.*

Больше предложений здесь: [сказать не подумав](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B2) и [ляпнуть не подумав](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B2).

2. В последнем предложении запятая нужна. Вот только где?

**Сказал я, просто не подумав.** Деепричастный оборот распространен и находится не сразу после сказуемого. (Сравните: *Она сидела ожидая. – Она сидела, ожидая ответа.*)

**Сказал я просто, не подумав.** Однородные обстоятельства разделены запятой.

[Обособление обстоятельств](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/721-252_obosoblenie_obstoyatelstv.html)

Answer (score 1):

1) ***Сказал не подУмав. СказАл, не подУмав.***

Возможны оба варианта. Обособление зависит от позиции оборота и структуры предложения. В значении наречия не обособляется, но может обозначать добавочное действие при обособлении. Не обособляется, если логическое ударение падает на оборот.

Вася собирается стать десантником, ― сказала я **не подумав**. [Маша Трауб. (2008)]

Да я не **подумав** сказал, мне отсюда спускаться-то нельзя. [Р. А. Белецкий. (1998)]

Казалось, в этой тишине не стоит ничего говорить, **не подумав**, ― такое большое таилось в ней значение. [Алексей Иванов. Географ глобус пропил (2002)]

2) ***Ляпнул не подУмав. ЛЯпнул, не подУмав*.**  Чаще не обособляется, но обособление не запрещается.

***Ляпнул не подУмавши*.** Это разговорно-просторечный стиль, не обособляется.

**ЛЯпнула, не подУмав,** теперь молчи ... [Екатерина Завершнева. Высотка (2012)]

3) ***СказАл я, просто не подУмав.***

Распространенный оборот обособляется, обозначая добавочное действие.